# Is there a way to update an object in an array of a document by query in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, nodes

I have got a data structure:

```
{
  field: 1, 
  field: 3,
  field: [
    { _id: xxx , subfield: 1 },
    { _id: xxx , subfield: 1 },
  ] 
}
```

I need to update a certain element in the array.

So far I can only do that by pulling out old object and pushing in a new one, but it changes the file order.

My implementation:

```
            const product = await ProductModel.findOne({ _id: productID });
            const price = product.prices.find( (price: any) => price._id == id );

            if(!price) {
                throw {
                    type: 'ProductPriceError',
                    code: 404,
                    message: `Coundn't find price with provided ID: ${id}`,
                    success: false,
                }
            }

            product.prices.pull({ _id: id })
            product.prices.push(Object.assign(price, payload))
            await product.save()
```

and I wonder if there is any atomic way to implement that. Because this approach doesn't seem to be secured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can update a particular object in the array if you can find it.
Have a look at the positional '$' operator [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/).

Your current implementation using mongoose will then be somewhat like this:

```
 await ProductModel.updateOne(
      { _id: productID, 'prices._id': id },//Finding Product with the particular price
      { $set: { 'prices.$.subField': subFieldValue } },
 );
```

Notice the '$' symbol in *prices.$.subField*. MongoDB is smart enough to only update the element at the index which was found by the query.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there any way to pass a payload object not mentioning all the fields in the update like so:  `{ $set: { 'prices.$': payload } }`. Would it work this way?

Comment: I haven't tried that. It's been more than a year since I worked with mongoose :).
But as per the docs this should work.
From the docs:
`db.collection.update(
   { <array>: value ... },
   { <update operator>: { "<array>.$" : value } }
)`

Comment: Yes, it does. You saved a lot of time. Thanks for being around again!

Comment: What are you working with now if not a secret?

Comment: Glad to be of help!

Comment: Haha
Mostly PSQL.

Comment: I've noticed more and more people are swtiching over Postres. Is that the way better than mongoose in perfomance or just a stack change?

Comment: It depends on what you are building. But generally speaking for large projects SQL is a lot better due to its schema strictness and query abilities. When you have a big team working on a single project, having a schema  becomes necessary.
ORMs like Mongoose do provide those to some extent but its not something native to MongoDB.

Comment: You know, it works well with updates. but there is another issue. If there is not product with provided id it flows silently with no error and when it updates the existing one it's not returning the updated object. Even with `{ new: true}` option. Have any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at what updateOne returns [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/#returns)
You will get an idea of what to do.